# Changes made by JS userscript don't appear to be seen by web application

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey, tampermonkey, userscripts

I am writing a tampermonkey script that, at its core, just checks and unchecks boxes in a form. That is managed by a function like the following:

```
function selectCheckbox(box) {
    box.classList.add("checked");
};
```

The changes to the element appear as the following HTML changes:

```
<a href="#" class</a>
```

to

```
<a href="#" class="checked"</a>
```

The checkboxes are visually being checked in the form, and upon inspecting the elements, the changes that occur happen in all of the same ways that they do when you manually check the box.  When the form is submitted, however, the application acts as if no boxes are checked at all.

Is this normal? Is there some additional thing that needs to happen to cause these changes to persist?

Answer (score 0):

Change the checked property to true or false.

```
function selectCheckbox(box) {
    box.checked = true;
}

function unSelectCheckbox(box) {
    box.checked = false;
}
```

You do not have to add a class.